# ruby - refactoring if else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring

I've tried reading some tutorials on refactoring and I am struggling with conditionals.  I don't want to use a ternary operator but maybe this should be extracted in a method?  Or is there a smart way to use map?

```
detail.stated = if value[:stated].blank?
                  nil
                elsif value[:stated] == "Incomplete"
                  nil
                elsif value[:is_ratio] == "true"
                  value[:stated] == "true"
                else
                  apply_currency_increment_for_save(value[:stated])
                end
```

Comment: Is this a Rails code? - `blank?` is defined by Rails, not part of Ruby

Comment: What do you want to do if it is nil ? like raise an error / die / exit ?

Comment: just want to return nil

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you move this logic into a method, it can be made a lot cleaner thanks to early `return` (and keyword arguments):

```
def stated?(stated:, is_ratio: nil, **)
  return if stated.blank? || stated == "Incomplete"
  return stated == "true" if is_ratio == "true"
  apply_currency_increment_for_save(stated)
end
```

Then...

```
detail.stated = stated?(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stated = value[:stated]
detail.stated = case
  when stated.blank? || stated == "Incomplete"
    nil
  when value[:is_ratio] == "true"
    value[:stated] == "true"
  else
    apply_currency_increment_for_save stated
end
```

*What's happening:*    when `case` is used without an expression, it becomes the civilized equivalent of an `if ... elsif ... else ... fi.`

You can use its result, too, just like with `if...end`.

Answer (score 1):

Move the code into `apply_currency_increment_for_save`
and do:

```
def apply_currency_increment_for_save(value)
  return if value.nil? || value == "Incomplete"
  return "true" if value == "true"
  # rest of the code. Or move into another function if its too complex
end
```

The logic is encapsulated and it takes 2 lines only

Comment: The logic of `apply_currency_increment_for_save` will now get messed up as it is doing more than "apply currency increment" as in case when it returns "true" -  in a way, it will violate single responsibility principle (SRP)

Comment: I don't agree, as the responsibility is getting  `stated` from `value`. So you can just rename it to `parse_stated` or something like that. Or, as I commented, you can move the rest of the code to another function. With the current code it is also not very clear why should a function called `apply_currency_increment_for_save` return a state. The main idea is to remove the case and push it down to a function, where it's much more readable

Answer (score 0):

I like @Jordan's suggestion.  However, it seems the call is incomplete -- the 'is_ratio' parameter is also selected from value but not supplied.

Just for the sake of argument I'll suggest that you could go one step further and provide a *class* that is very narrowly focused on evaluating a "stated" value.  This might seem extreme but it fits with the notion of single responsibility (the responsibility is evaluating "value" for stated -- while the 'detail' object might be focused on something else and merely makes use of the evaluation).

It'd look something like this:

```
class StatedEvaluator
  attr_reader :value, :is_ratio

  def initialize(value = {})
    @value = ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(value.fetch(:stated, ''))
    @is_ratio = ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(value.fetch(:is_ratio, ''))
  end

  def stated
    return nil if value.blank? || value.Incomplete?
    return value.true? if is_ratio.true?
    apply_currency_increment_for_save(value)
  end
end

detail.stated = StatedEvaluator.new(value).stated
```

Note that this makes use of Rails' [StringInquirer class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/StringInquirer.html).

Comment: "However, it seems the call is incomplete..." It sounds like maybe you're not familiar with [keyword arguments](https://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+keyword+arguments) in Ruby. The method signature `def stated?(stated:, is_ratio: nil)` indicates that the method takes a Hash as an argument and the Hash values with the keys `:stated` and `:is_ratio` will be extracted from it into the local variables `stated` and `is_ratio`, respectively (the latter with a default value of `nil` in its absence).

Comment: Thanks, Jordan.  I am, in fact, familiar with keyword arguments.  My comment is a bit off.  The issue that could arise from your example is related to the potential for the hash to have more keys than just 'stated' and 'is_ratio'.  Sorry for the mixup.