# What is an efficient way to refactor a heavy if statement in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, refactoring, code-structure

**What is an efficient way to refactor a heavy if statement?**

*All suggestions are encouraged...*

```
<% if @user.plan_id == 1 %>
      <span class="label label-info">Plan1</span>
  <% elsif @user.plan_id == 2 %>
      <span class="label label-warning">Plan2</span>
  <% elsif @user.plan_id == 3 %>
      <span class="label label-info">Plan3</span>
  <% elsif @user.plan_id == 4 %>
      <span class="label label-warning">Plan4</span>
  <% elsif @user.plan_id == 5 %>
      <span class="label label-info">Plan5</span>
  <% elsif @user.plan_id == 6 %>
      <span class="label label-warning">Plan6</span>
  <% elsif @user.plan_id == 7 %>
      <span class="label label-info">Plan7</span>   
  <% elsif @user.plan_id == 8 %>
      <span class="label label-warning">Plan8</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: use [case](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case) statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275608/ruby-refactoring-if-else-statement

Comment: Try searching stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby-on-rails%5D+refactoring+if+else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for a helper module, something like this:

```
module UserPlanHelper
  PLANS = {
    1 => [ "info", "Plan1" ],
    2 => [ "warning", "Plan2" ],
    3 => [ "info", "Plan3" ],
    4 => [ "warning", "Plan4" ],
    5 => [ "info", "Plan5" ],
    6 => [ "warning", "Plan6" ],
    7 => [ "info", "Plan7" ],
    8 => [ "warning", "Plan8" ]
  }

  def plan_details(plan_id)
    yield(PLANS[plan_id])
  end
end
```

If used in your controller this simplifies your code to something like:

```
<%= plan_details(@user.plan_id) do |label_class, label| %>
  <span class="label label-<%= label_class %>"><%= label %></span>
<%- end %>
```

Comment: Small question: what's the purpose/benefit of adding `yield` to `plan_details` method?

Comment: @UtsavKesharwani It means you can structure it as `plan_details(...) do` with a block inside rather than having to create local variables.

Comment: `yield` seems to be oddly underutilized outside of framework-level code in Ruby. Or maybe it is just the code I've ended looking at.

Comment: @muistooshort I use it all the time, but I do like to lean more heavily on the quasi-functional programming you can do with it.

Comment: Same here. And lots of lambdas to make my `Enumerable` chains easier to read. I've even been know to write my own classes rather than relying on the mess of nested hashes and arrays that everyone seems to like :)

Answer (score 2):

Does `plan_id` reference a `Plan` model? If not, I'd suggest creating one, with a `label` attribute and an `elite` flag. Then, your statement would be:

```
<span class="label label-<%= @user.plan.elite ? 'warning' : 'info' %>}">
  <%= @user.plan.label %>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`

```
<% case @user.plan_id %>
<% when 1 %>
    <span class="label label-info">CONTRIBUTOR</span>
<% when 2 %>
    <span class="label label-warning">ELITE CONTRIBUTOR</span>
<% when 3 %>
     <span class="label label-info">TECHNICIAN</span>
<% when 4 %>
     <span class="label label-warning">ELITE TECHNICIAN</span>
<% when 5 %>
     <span class="label label-info">CENTER</span>
<% when 6 %>
     <span class="label label-warning">ELITE CENTER</span>
<% when 7 %>
     <span class="label label-info">AFFAIR</span>   
<% when 8 %>
      <span class="label label-warning">ELITE AFFAIR</span>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a helper method:

```
def plan_hash
  {
    1 => { :klass => "label-info",    :description => "Plan1" },
    2 => { :klass => "label-warning", :description => "Plan2" },
    3 => { :klass => "label-info",    :description => "Plan3" },
    4 => { :klass => "label-warning", :description => "Plan4" },
    5 => { :klass => "label-info",    :description => "Plan5" },
    6 => { :klass => "label-warning", :description => "Plan6" },
    7 => { :klass => "label-info",    :description => "Plan7" },
    8 => { :klass => "label-warning", :description => "Plan8" }
  }
end
```

Then, in your view:

```
<span class="label <%= plan_hash[@user.plan_id][:klass] %>"><%= plan_hash[@user.plan_id][:description] %></span>
```

Comment: If there is some correlation between the `klass`, and `description`, I can refactor the helper method. Since the user hasn't specified anything as such, I have kept it to be plain and simple. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="label label-<%= @user.add_warning? ? 'warning' : 'info' %>">
  Plan<%= @user.plan_id.to_s %>
</span>
```

Use this method in your user model:

```
def add_warning?
  self.plan_id.in?([2, 4, 6, 8])
end
```